# Configure interface order in `netstat -rn` output

Tags: windows, networking, netstat

When I'm typing `netstat -rn`, I'm getting the following output:

```
===========================================================================
Interface list
 33...........................myvpn.com
 16...00 ff ca 62 5e 09 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 20...60 45 cb a8 9f 17 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================
...
```

myvpn.com is the adapter for the VPN connection.
The first number is some kind of interface metric. I want to change it, because I suspect that Windows does not use DNS servers provided by that VPN connection because of that metric.
I tried to change metric in advanced adapter settings, but it's a different metric (which showed later in routing table), and metric in this table did not change. I also tried to use PowerShell command `Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric` but it did not change that metric either.
I think that it's somewhere in the registry, but I wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number is not a metric nor priority; it's merely a unique ID – "interface index" – assigned from a counter. The first interface created by the OS gets 1, the second gets 2, and so on. Commands that require specifying an interface will often accept either the name *or* the ifIndex.

The interface index does not influence route order nor DNS server order. (Routes are sorted by prefix length, then by the route's own metric. I'm not sure about DNS servers, but I think Windows has an "interface priority" window elsewhere.)